# Pasword remove hashing: convert MD5 to normal hashing PHP

Tags: php, hash, md5

I am unsure as to how to convert an MD5 dehashing into a normal verification. I would like to change a hashed string to standard one. I am generating the hashed password as `echo password_hash(".......", PASSWORD_DEFAULT);` , just don't know how to check it in login form. My workflow is below:

```
 if (isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = md5($_POST['password']);

    if (empty($username) or empty($password)) {
        $error = 'Proszę podać login i hasło !';
    } else {
        
        $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = ? AND user_password = ?");

        $query->bindValue(1, $username);
        $query->bindValue(2, $password);
         
        $query->execute();

        $num = $query->rowCount();

        if ($num == 1) {
            //user entered correct details
            $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
            
            header('Location: index.php');
            exit();
```

Comment: Use [`password_hash()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php). Those pages have some examples on their use.

Comment: Instead of replacing the hashing method, you should use the `password` functions directly; see [password_hash](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [password_verify](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php). You'll probably have to introduce a new column to keep the "new" password hash, and then replace them as people log in. After some time (3? 6? months) all users that haven't gotten a new password can have their passwords disabled and use the "forgotten password" function to log in.

Comment: There is no such thing as dehashing. Hashing is a one-way operation. If you want to check the password, you hash the received password again and compare the result to the stored hash. This is how the two previously recommended functions work.

Comment: ok, thx for info and do you know maybe how to code it correctly ? $password = md5($_POST['password']);